# Youtube API, check if a video has been modified

Tags: php, api, zend-framework, youtube

I'm using YouTube API with ZendGdata library on my CMS.

I retrieve all videos of a member and I dynamically create related articles all nigths with a cron.

I need to know if a video has been modified by the member (title, description...), maybe with a date or something. I can retrieve all datas and check the difference but it's not very "light".

Is there a data like that in this API ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and finally i decided to add a hash column to the DB so I can know if something has changed.

Something like:

```
$playlist['publishDate'] = $playlistJson['items'][0]['snippet']['publishedAt'];
$playlist['youtubeId'] = $playlistJson['items'][0]['id'];
$playlist['title'] = $playlistJson['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
//...

$playlist['dataHash'] = md5(implode('--',$playlist));

$youtubePlaylistId=$mysqli->real_escape_string($playlist['youtubeId']);

$sResult=$mysqli->query("SELECT dataHash FROM channel WHERE youtubeId=$youtubePlaylistId LIMIT 1") or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

if($sResult->num_rows == 1) {
    while ($sRow = $sResult->fetch_assoc()) {
        $currentDataHash =$sRow['dataHash'];
    }
    if ($currentDataHash==$playlist['dataHash']) {
        //playlist exists and data is identical
    } else {
        //playlist exists but data needs refresh
    }
} else {
    //playlist does not exist
}
```